# config.disallowedContent does not work fully In trying to configure CKEditor for a Responsive CMS,

Tags: ckeditor

I have developed a responsive CMS in which CKEditor is employed for content input.
(Sorry for my English, it is not my maternal language)
Sites produced by the CMS, need to adjust transparently to the device where they are shown.
Almost everthing is fine, but my customers do a lot of cut and paste from several spurces.
I Added the "Paste from word" plugin which does a fantastic job of cleaning bloated HTML, but does not cover the last mile for a responsive CMS, as tables and cells keep  their width, expressed as a style, which prevents the CMS engine to apply the best suitable style for a particular device.
After long hours of googling and testing, I found a partial solution by using:

```
disallowedContent : 'table {width*};
```

While calling my particular CKEditor Instance.

This clears up the original table width definition, but I also need to clear Th and Td width definitions which might have or might be set with un-appropiate dimentions for a responsive page, specially when seen on a portrait mode.

I tryied changing the plugins/pastefromword/filter/default.js lines 1050...1053 from:

```
[ ( /^width|height$/ ), null, function( value, element ) {
if ( element.name in {  table: 1,  th: 1,  td: 1, mg: 1 } )
return value;,
```

To:

```
[ ( /^width|height$/ ), null, function( value, element ) {
if ( element.name in {  table: 0,  th: 0,  td: 0, img: 1 } )
return value;
```

or:

```
[ ( /^width|height$/ ), null, function( value, element ) {
if ( element.name in {  img: 1 } )
return value;
```

To no avail, and:

I tried many combinations of the disallowedContent setting, for example like:

```
disallowedContent : 'table {width*}; td {width*} '
```

or:

```
disallowedContent : 'table th td {width*} '
```

Which now do not clear and prevent the table dialog from setting a table width, neither prevent but allow the  cell properties dialog to set the cell with.

Is this a bug or likelly I am doing something wrong.

A solution to this will be gratly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your case. I used two CKEditor instances, one with the default configuration and another with:

```
disallowedContent : 'table {width*}; tr {width*}; td {width*};'
```

Tried a few things:

1. Copy from one editor instance to another.
2. Copy from Word to both instances.
3. Insert a new table via the Table plugin/dialog.

---

In all cases the following attribute was present in the first instance (with the default configuration):

```
style="width:..px"
```

In the second instance (with `config.disallowedContent`), the `width` parameter from `table` and `td` elements was removed while pasting/inserting. It seems it works fine and your case may be more specific or there are some errors in your configuration.

I did all tests on Windows 7 with Chrome and MS Word 2013. CKEditor version 4.5.7.

Can you provide more details on your use case or steps how to recreate it?